# If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and is an additive homomorphism then $f(x)=f(1)x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Here's the question:

> Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous which is also an
>   additive homomorphism, that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x.y
>  \in\mathbb{R}$. Then show that $f(x)=\lambda x $ where $ \lambda =
> f(1)$.

Truth to be told, I have no idea how to solve this problem. Here's what the authors have discussed before this Exercise.

> Let $J\subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $f\colon J\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $a\in J$. We say that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $J$ with $\lim x_n =a$, we have $\lim f(x_n) = f(a)$. We also say that $f$ is continuous  on $J$ if it is continuous at every point $a\in J$.

They discuss few examples before dropping this exercise. $\epsilon- \delta$ definition of continuity has not been defined yet and this is the first section of the chapter.

I'd appreciate it if you give me some hints instead of solving it entirely.

Comment: Hint. Prove this first for integers, then for rational numbers, then use the fact that the rationals are dense and your definition of continuity.

Comment: You asked just for hints, so use them and don't look at the posted answers to the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2798558) and the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$.